# C# ReceiveAsync Error

Tags: c#

Im currently developing an appserver. I would like to use AcceptAsync method. I got error "Object reference not set to instance of object." when calling ReceiveAsync method. If there any come up with this problem and got the solution to it?

```
public class AppServer
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12345));
        serverSocket.Listen(100);

        SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(e_Completed);

        bool raiseEvent = serverSocket.AcceptAsync(e);
        if (!raiseEvent)
            AcceptCallback(e);
    }

    void e_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        AcceptCallback(e);
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        readEventArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(readEventArgs_Completed);

        Socket clientSocket = e.AcceptSocket;
        bool raiseEvent = clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs); // <-- Error goes here
        if (!raiseEvent)
            ReceiveCallback(readEventArgs);
    }

    void readEventArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        ReceiveCallback(e);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming if you put a breakpoint on that line then clientSocket (and therefore e.AcceptSocket) is null?  What does e.SocketError return?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem and `clientSocket` is *not* `null`, I'm unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I managed to figure it out.
You need to provide to your SocketAsyncEventArgs object a data buffer (byte array) to store the data received before calling ReceiveAsync(e).

```
void e_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    e.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    AcceptCallback(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you in two place accept socket. If you remove

```
 AcceptCallback(e);
```

from e_Completed everything is working.

It's link to example asynchronous server:

[a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx)

Comment: Blindly pull stuff out until it works is not a good method for software. It would be good if you try to understand what causes the error and fix it. And here the code is trying to receive data from an async socket without first allocating and assigning a receive buffer. That's what should be fixed.